# Apply styles to blockquote element with the WYSIWYG editor

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, functions, css

I have a blockquote and I can float it left or right if I want by going into the html editor and adding class="alignleft" etc. Is there any way I can make that available to a non tech individual with a button or plugin / function or something. I think i'm looking at a tinymce plugin but i've never done anything with that area; so hoping to avoid that at this time if at all possible. If that is what I need would anyone have a code snippit or a link to a good tutorial. I imagine it's a fairly common thing to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/adding-custom-styles-in-wordpress-tinymce-editor/) gives you a short plugin you can modify to create a "styles" drop down with the "alignleft" and "alignright" classes in it.

As a note, just to stay out of WordPress's way, I might choose a different class or at least something prefixed like me-alignleft.